# Expose Confluent Kafka outside of the cluster but inside of the GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, kafka, helm

I've installed Confluent Kafka OSS using their official helm chart: https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts

However, I would like to consume Kafka topics in a GCP Dataflow so this mean, I guess, that I need to make the Kafka pods available *outside* the K8s cluster.

1. I was not able to find a parameter into the helm chart to switch from ClusterIP to Node Balancers (for each broker, I guess)
2. Assuming that I will, how to restrict the access to GCP resources (eventually the same project in which the K8s cluster lies) only?

Answer (score 0):

On the first question, you don't need to change the `ClusterIP` resources directly in the chart, as these are exposing your applications within the cluster. You can instead [create other types of external services to expose your application on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps).

Regarding the second one and since you're running on GKE, you can just create a [private GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters) that will restrict access to the same VPC by default.